# Why aren't unused zero-initialized vectors removed by optimization?

Tags: rust, compilation

If I write a method that initializes a `Vec` with a non-zero value and call it a couple of times from `main()`, then when I build with `--release` (`-O3`) the compiler optimizes everything away into effectively a no-op:

#### Code

```rust
fn allocate() {
    let _a = vec![1; 100];
}

pub fn main() {
    allocate();
    allocate();
}
```

#### Output

```
example::main:
        ret
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/hesW8foT9)

However, if I instead initialize it with *zero*, the result is drastically different:

#### Code

```rust
fn allocate() {
    let _a = vec![0; 100];
}

pub fn main() {
    allocate();
    allocate();
}
```

#### Output

```
example::main:
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 400
        mov     esi, 4
        call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_alloc_zeroed@GOTPCREL]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB0_2
        mov     esi, 400
        mov     edx, 4
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_dealloc@GOTPCREL]
        mov     edi, 400
        mov     esi, 4
        call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_alloc_zeroed@GOTPCREL]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB0_2
        mov     esi, 400
        mov     edx, 4
        mov     rdi, rax
        pop     rax
        jmp     qword ptr [rip + __rust_dealloc@GOTPCREL]
.LBB0_2:
        mov     edi, 400
        mov     esi, 4
        call    qword ptr [rip + alloc::alloc::handle_alloc_error@GOTPCREL]
        ud2
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/s7hfzrfM8)

Why does the compiler keep the zero-initialization instructions even though it is literally allocating it and immediately deallocating it, but optimize everything away if you initialize with anything else?

Comment: Seems like a missed-optimization bug.  You could report it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point, I was assuming it was intended. I've opened an issue for it in case it is indeed a bug.

Comment: For reference: [the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90032).